# Count a mean score for multiple rows

Tags: r

```
username,age,face_type,verified,beauty,race_type,neutral,negative,positive,compound,id,date_time,category
mimi__ramos,24,human,False,50,black,0.769,0.231,0.0,-0.765,1316809948311945217,2020-10-16,Poultry
_LucyParker,28,human,False,53,white,0.655,0.116,0.228,0.743,1314521977206370304,2020-10-09,Poultry
bttrhmsndgrdns,25,human,False,36,white,0.957,0.0,0.043,0.1901,1314518987032670208,2020-10-09,Poultry
chicken__lady,27,human,False,64,white,0.738,0.131,0.131,0.0,1313203033598287880,2020-10-06,Poultry
TheSolape,30,human,False,46,black,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1313098409277100033,2020-10-05,Poultry
```

Since each **username** may have multiple observations, I hope to get user-level results of the Mean(compound). I used the below code, but it only shows two columns: username and mean_compound

```
data_new %>% group_by(username) %>% summarise(mean_compound=mean(compound))
# A tibble: 683,510 x 2
   username          mean_compound
   <fct>                     <dbl>
 1 ""                       -0.394
 2 "____________bug"         0.735
 3 "____________Nia"         0.670
 4 "________amee"           -0.439
 5 "________Ash"             0.440
 6 "________kasey"           0.958
 7 "________lydia"          -0.572
 8 "_______2_s__"            0    
 9 "_______bbyg"             0.956
10 "_______DesireMe"        -0.525
```

1. How can I generate a new **User-level** table having variables: username, age, face_type,
   verified, beauty, Mean_compound, Mean_positive, Mean_negative, Mean_neutural, id, date_time?
2. Also, a id may have different categories, is there a way to show it in the samee table?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `summarise`, use `mutate` that creates a new column in the data.  If need to return only the first row, use `slice_head`

```
library(dplyr)
data_new %>%
  group_by(username) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(compound, positive, neutral, negative), 
          ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE), .names = 'mean_{.col}')) %>%
  slice_head(n = 1) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, what can I do if I want to add four new columns: mean(compound), mean(positive), mean(neutral), mean(negative)?

Comment: @Zhen you can use `mutate` with `across` updated